# Fetching messages in real time with Telethon from a Telegram channel

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to fetch messages in real time from some Telegram channels. My code is as follow:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
import config

client = TelegramClient('anon', config.api_id, config.api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='channel'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)
```

The config document contains my credentials. Now this works, except that at some points there are delays of some seconds. And for some channels it completely misses some of the messages if I let the script run long enough. I also use Anaconda.
Is there some workaround to get real time messages without missing any of them?

Comment: buy faster computer and/or faster network connection. Some delays may depend on traffic in network and you can't change it.

Comment: If you have a lot of active sessions, or the channel is very active, Telegram will deliver the updates more slowly.

Comment: So you confirm that this code should give me messages in real time?

Comment: Yes, that's the right code to get messages in real time from `@channel` (assuming you use `client.run_until_disconnected()` in the end or similar.